# Evaluating the limit $\displaystyle \lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{(x^2+1)}{(x-1)}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$

Tags: calculus, limits

How would you solve this limit: 
$$
\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{x^2+1}{x-1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
I was having trouble evaluating this limit. Can someone help?

Comment: And may you show us some work you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\lim _{x\to \infty }\frac{(x^2+1)}{(x-1)}sin(\frac{1}{x}) &= \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{((\frac{1}{t})^2+1)\sin(t)}{(\frac{1}{t}-1)} \\
&= \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{(\frac{1+t^2}{t^2})\sin(t)}{\frac{1-t}{t}} \\
&= \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{(1+t^2)\sin(t)}{t(1-t)} \\
&= \lim _{t \to 0}\frac{(1+t^2)\cos(t)+2t\sin t}{(1-2t)} \\
&= \frac{(1+0^2)\cos(0)+20\sin 0}{(1-2(0))} \\
&= \frac{1+0}{1} \\
&= 1 \\
\end{align}$$

Use of $\frac{0}{0}$ version of L'Hopital rule to get 4th equality.

Comment: Your first application of L'Hopital's Rule is not valid since it is of the form $\frac{\infty\cdot 0}{\infty}$.

Comment: Correct now....

Answer (score 5):

Put $\frac{1}{x}=t$

so the equation reduces to $\dfrac{(1+t^2)\sin t}{t-t^2}$ which is in $\frac{0}{0}$ form 
Applying L'Hospitals rule;

$\dfrac{2t\sin t+(1+t^2)\cos t}{1-2t}\rightarrow 1 $ as $t\rightarrow 0$

Comment: minor point but it should be $\dfrac{2t\sin t+(1+t^2)\cos t}{1-2t}\rightarrow 1$

Comment: thanks @1234 for correcting

Answer (score 3):

This is old, but it deserves a solution without L'hopital. Substitute $u = x^{-1}$ so that

$$\frac{(1 + u^2) \sin u}{u - u^2} \xrightarrow[\sin u \sim u \ \text{as} \ u \to 0^+]{} \frac{1+u^2}{1 - u} \xrightarrow{}1$$

Answer (score 1):

for $x$ large, we have  $$\sin(1/x) = 1/x + \cdots, \frac{x^2 + 1}{x-1} = x + \cdots$$ so the 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{x^2 + 1}{x-1} \sin(\frac{1}{x}) = 1 $$